# How to get multiple streams in a peerConnection

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

Hello I am going to create a surveillance system. I would like to get a webcam video and a shared screen, but using addtrack will only get the media stream I declared later. Is there any way to get both streams.
thanks.

here is code offer side

```
let stream = video.srcObject;
let stream2 = shareVideo.srcObject;
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));
stream2.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream2));
```

and here is answer side

```
peerConnections[id].ontrack = (event) => {
console.log(event);
```

when i checked log. event has one track and stream[0] has mediastream bu steam[1] has no mediastream

Comment: the ontrack only adds the tracks one by one. So you will have multiple ontrack events called with each only one track

Comment: thanks for replying.  i'm stuck with calling multiple ontrack....  because i use ontrack only once when callee makes createAnswer....

Comment: What is the problem with calling it multiple times ?